# IPC vs Frequency in intel nehalem processor

Tags: multithreading, architecture, parallel-processing, intel, multicore

I'm doing some experiments with intel Nehalem processor. I've noticed for parallel computation each core attains maximum IPC level at different cpu frequency and then if I increase frequency , IPC go down. The IPC value is low at lower frequency and very high frequency.

Could anyone please explain this behavior of IPC (Instructions Per Cycle).

Thanks and regards

Comment: What do you mean by IPC?  Inter-process communication is probably the most common meaning, but it isn't entirely clear that's what you mean because there are lots of different IPC mechanisms and you've not specified which you might be using.

Comment: Instructions Per Cycle.

Comment: I'll take a shot at it.  Processors are often limited by how fast they can access memory.  The caches help a lot but there's only so much they can do.  Increasing the core frequency affects only the execution engines on the core, it doesn't make memory faster.  Faced with a fixed latency to access memory, inevitably the number of instructions per cycle must go down.